# Missing 'Page Attributes'

Tags: templates, page-template

I'm building my own theme and so far so good.

I created a template and named it correctly but it doesn't appear in any drop-down or indeed there's even no page attribute option at all.

Do I need to add something to the functions file?

There is nothing either in 'screen options'

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Top Ten
 * Template Post Type: post, page, product
 */

get_header();  ?>
```

I was missing the `Template Post Type`

Comment: Can you be more precise in the answer, what it was missing? Was it maybe the `<?php`? Or even the `get_header()`?

Comment: Missing the "Template Post Type <<<<"

Comment: @Henry, In which file you have added the above code?